# How to allow access to the site root document in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

What I am trying to accomplish looks quite simple: allow the site's `index.html` for everybody and hide everything else from everybody.

Needless to say the `index.html` file can be addressed as `http://example.com/index.html` or just `http://example.com/`.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

<Files "index.html">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

works for the first case (when a user specifies the document name explicitly) but does not work for the second (when just the site root URL is supplied and the document is chosen as the default).

What syntax should I use?

Comment: I just tested and a `Files` directive on the index.html was also applied on the URL without the index.html specified with apache 2.2...

Comment: Have you added `Order Deny,Allow` and `Deny from all` before the Files section, @HBruijn?

Comment: No I didn't, but that's exactly the reason I follow the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) and routinely avoid .htaccess files. Then the [order of precedence](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin) is generally better defined. I assume that `/` in combination with a .htaccess file and the `Deny from all` is  of the same priority as location directive, overriding a files directive which should provide the exception to the deny all... Go to the main httpd.config and use a `Directory` directive to deny from all and override with the `Files` directive.

Comment: Nice to know (but still counterintuitive as `FilesMatch` directive works and overrides `Deny from all` successfully, for example). But I don't have access to httpd.config in this project, it's a shared hosting kind, all I have is FTP access to my www documents root directory.

Comment: I believe it's because "/" is a directory and not a file